# Best way to model system with a single interface used in different ways in java

Tags: java, interface, oop, data-modeling

I have a class that implements an interface

```
class TopLevel implements TopLevelOperations
```

inside TopLevel the operations are implemented in 2 different ways. So some of the operations in TopLevelOperations need to be called as SOAP client calls and some as restful calls.

What would be the best way to model this? Create additional two interfaces SOAPOperations and RESTOperations to specify what is the responsibility of restful and SOAP respectively ? Then use two other classes internally that implement those interfaces? The motivation is that I may one day want to swap out SOAP for some other approach.

Better way?

Edit: I also don't want different client code jumbled together in TopLevel as it currently is.

Comment: When you "swap out" implementations, are you OK with changing what class it extends?  If so, you could have an abstract class for each that implement the same interface.

Comment: Does TopLevelOperations simply delegate to external web services, or does it *implement* the web services?

Comment: TopLevelOperations actually needs to be the client that invokes those operations.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is separate the transport layer from the payload.
Both requests over the network are over HTTP but the payload is different, i.e. it is wrapped in a SOAP envelope in one case and pure xml data in REST.
So for the higher lever code you should have an interface that just sends a message, encapsulated in an object.
The implementation of this interface converts the message to XML (via DOM or JAXB etc).
Then this XML is passed to a transport layer to be send over HTTP **or** wrapped in a SOAP message **before passing** it to the transport layer.
The transport layer can be just a concrete class that is as simple as:

```
public class HttpClient{

      public String sendMsg(String xml){
       //Use some HTTP client to send message and return the response.
      //The input could be SOAP or plain xml app data
      //The output could be SOAP or plain xml app data
      }
    }
```

So the user configures your objects to use SOAP or not.
The application code is only aware of the interface to send message.
In your implementation, because of the separation of XML transformation and HTTP transport layers you can swap implementations or add new ones.

Comment: I could do that but there may be yet another client where the message may not rely on XML.

Comment: That is ok.The idea is that you separate the various layers.You could instead have a `public byte[] sendMesg(byte[] data)` and depend on the actual object to covert `data` to xml or whatever. Or you could add a new transport e.g. over raw TCP instead of HTTP etc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the solution needs to be that complex (assuming I understand the problem of course...):

1. Make sure `TopLevelOperations` declares all the methods a client can use.  Do so in a protocol-independent way, e.g. `TopLevelOperations.doFoo()`, not `TopLevelOperations.doFooOverSOAP()`
2. Implement `TopLevel` as your first version of the interface using SOAP/REST as appropriate.
3. Ensure clients only ever reference `TopLevelOperations` when declaring references - never the implementing class
4. Use whatever mechanism is appropriate for your app to inject the appropriate implementation into the clients (Dependency Injection / Factory / ...).

If / when you want to re-implement the methods using a different transport/protocol just create another class (`TopLevelNew`) that implements `TopLevelOperations`.  Then inject it into clients instead of `TopLevel` in step 4 above.

Deciding which implementation to use is then an application-level configuration decision, not something the clients have to be aware of.

hth.

[You may also want/need to use some helpers classes for the implementation, e.g. separating content from payload as per @user384706's answer.  But that's complementary to above (i.e. how to design the implementation vs. how to keep interface consistent for clients).]

Comment: That's good advice, but in this approach don't I still have both SOAP and REST operations in the same class TopLevel? The case is I may want to change only the REST part but keep SOAP identical. I would still need to change the entire class then.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'change the whole class'?  You'd only have to change the methods whose implementation changed from SOAP to REST or vice-versa.  (You'd have to re-deploy the whole class - perhaps that's what you mean by "change"?)